# How to write message strings to a file using vim script?

Tags: vimscript, macvim

I would like to create two functions, one for sending a message string to Vim's own messaging system and one to dump the message string to a file.

Now, I have already progressed in figuring this out with different approaches however, my solution is not elegant enough and sometimes the messages sent to `:messages` are getting lost on the status line at the moment of printing them out. However once I run `:messages` I can see those *skipped* messages in there. So this must be related to the way I deal with new lines etc. Here are bits of my script that should illustrate what approaches I have tried so far:

```
" Lets assume this is a part of the SendToStatus() function
" and it is a bit like a pseudo-code.
execute 'echohl' error
for l:line in split('My message.', '\\n')
  echomsg l:line
endfor
echohl NONE
```

The traditional way of sending the messages to `:messages` works fine on it's own. The problems start when I use the following to write the same message to a file:

```
" Lets assume this is a part of the SendToFile() function
" and this is also a bit like a pseudo-code.
try
    echon "\r"
    execute 'redir >> ' . l:file
    silent echomsg l:msgString
    silent echo "\n"
    silent! redir END
catch /E190:/
    throw s:myException('Cannot write to file: %s', l:file)
end-try
```

So when I execute these commands one after another like this:

```
function! SomeMoreComplexWrapper() abort
    ...
    SendToStatus('some message')
    SendToFile('some message')
    ....
    SendToStatus('some more messages')
    ....
    SendToStatus('some more messages')
    SendToFile('even more messages')
    ...
endfunction
```

The strings are written to the file with no issues what so ever, however, the status messages are getting lost on some occasions. It must be the way the echoing order is managed.

I have also tried the `readfile()` and `writefile()` approaches, which worked just fine. This helped me to take the process of echoing to a file out of the equation, thus removed the need of dealing with `echo` and `echomsg` on both sides and only keep `echomsg` to send the strings to the `:message` facility. However I need to store the contents of my log file into a list and append the new string to that every time I need to send something to the file, which I find a bit scary.

Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: I am working on a fully functional example that will reproduce the issue. I will share that as soon as it works. However, I now know that in cases where `SendToFile()` is used consecutive, the following `SendToStatus()` will be dropped and will be only visible in the `:message` stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to that bit:

```
echon "\r"
```

... in the file dumper function, used to reset the cursor position. Stack multiple `SendToFile()` and you get the cursor aligned too many time causing the next `echom` commands to be not visible in the status line.

The solution (for now) is to use a variable `s:isFileStreamActive` that is set to 1 inside `SendToFile()` and to 0 inside `SendToStatus()`. In that way, consecutive `echon "\r"` commands can be skipped with an `if` statement:

```
if !s:isFileStreamActive
    echon "\r"
endif
```